# How to remove the part number from a part, but only in the table of contents, and keep its default article styling?

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, tocloft, parts

In short, I want to have an "un-numbered part", with its default article styling, but only in the table of contents, not in the actual document. Basically the same as `\renewcommand{\thepart}{}` but only for ToC, (and it should shift to the left appropriately to fill the missing number space).

---

Currently if do

```
\part{This is the part name}
\section{Section}
\subsection{subsection}
% etc.
```

I have the following in my ToC:

[image]

And what'd I'd like to have is this:

[image]

While my document body remains unchanged (I changed "Part" to "Section" for my project, shown in code bellow, sorry for the confusion):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{linktoc=all}
\usepackage{tocloft}

% I just redefined it a bit idk if it's relevant
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
\renewcommand{\partname}{Section}
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}
```

Comment: tocloft is for different "List of Stuff", not for styling the table of contents.  This is more along the lines of the titlesec and titletoc packages.  Have you looked into those?

Comment: Thank you, yeah it does seems to be what I need. I did try a bunch of answers on here that used titletoc, but I just could not figure how to make it not completely remove or screw up the default styling, which is why I decided to explicitly specify that in my question.